# Memory management with `addrinfo` structures

Tags: c, sockets, getaddrinfo

I've just started to work with UDP sockets in C and I have a question relating to memory management. Often examples show something of the following

```
struct addrinfo *result;    //to store results
struct addrinfo hints;      //to indicate information we want
:
:
:
if( (s = getaddrinfo(hostname, NULL, &hints, &result)) != 0){
  fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n",gai_strerror(s));
  exit(1);
}
:
:
:
//free the addrinfo struct
freeaddrinfo(result);
```

I've also seen the introduction of an additonal local `addrinfo` structure used in a `for` loop to cycle through the `result` for the sake of extracting a particular entry...something like this

```
struct addrinfo *entry;    //to store a result from linked list
:
:
:
for (entry = result; entry != NULL; entry = entry->ai_next)
{
:
:
:
}
```

My question is why is `result` the only structure that gets passed to `freeaddrinfo` and not `hints` or `entry`? In other words, I've never seen anyone call `freeaddrinfo(hints)`.

One other thing, should I be preallocating memory for or initializing structures of the form `addrinfo`? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: [Man page for getaddrinfo and freeaddrinfo](https://linux.die.net/man/3/freeaddrinfo) has the answer to your question

Comment: Just skimmed through...it's because `getaddrinfo` dynamically allocates the memory?

Comment: If that's the case, should I be pre-allocating memory / initializing  `entry` in the example above? Why doesn't that get passed to `freeaddrinfo` ?

Comment: Its difficult to answer your questions within the comments section. I'm going to reply with an answer

Comment: This question is not related to UDP at all, removing the tag.

Comment: It most often is a good idea to read the documentation prior to posting a more or less vague question on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *Just skimmed through...it's because getaddrinfo dynamically allocates the memory?*

Yes. More specifically, it allocates memory for the linkedlist pointed to by `result` pointer. Since the library is allocating memory on your behalf, library implementors have also providing you with an API to free the memory.

2. *If that's the case, should I be pre-allocating memory / initializing `entry` in the example above? Why doesn't that get passed to freeaddrinfo*

No. `entry` is just a variable used to iterate through the list. It is very much similar to

```
`for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`
```

loop you will find anywhere else. `i` is just an iterator.

You don't have to use `entry` variable at all if you don't want to. You can iterate through the linkedlist with just a while loop

```
while (result != NULL) {
    //Do what you have to do here

    result = result->ai_next;
}
```

If you observe closely, you will see that you are moving the `result` variable itself to the end of the list.  If you iterate this way, there is no way for you to free the memory since you have lost the starting address which was returned to you by getaddrinfo(). To get around this, you can save the starting address in a temp variable and then use the while loop. Just add this line before the while loop.

```
struct addrinfo *entry = result; //save the starting address
while (...) {

}
```

You can call free on `entry` pointer now, instead of `result`. The effect would be the same.

```
freeaddrinfo(entry);
```

Comment: Interesting...I thought iterators were only integers. Sounds like a can of worms opening :)

Comment: read about pointer arithmetic. It is a bit tricky at first to understand it. But it is needed if you want to use C language